# Clear app data in Windows 10 like you do in Android

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

In Android I can go to my applications and choose to wipe the application data, to reset the app. I'm using Windows 10 on desktop and I installed a game from the store, which I would like to reset my progress and start over, but I can't find such option in Windows. Is there any way to do this without unistalling and installing the app again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running [Insider Preview Build 14328](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/), you can reset app data [using the Settings tool under Apps & features](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48107-app-reset-windows-10-a.html). Not all apps support reset though.

If you're not running the Insider Preview build, you may need to run some tests to figure out which files you can safely delete to reset the app data.

Install the app, but don't start it yet. Find and copy the relevant package folder from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages` (sort by `Date modified` to find the newest package folders) and save it as "backup".

Now start the app and do something that might affect the default data (e.g. win a game, attempt a high score, save game, etc.)

Now copy the relevant package folder from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages` once again and compare the changes against the "backup" folder. You may want to use a folder comparison tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) to find the differences.

I noticed that to reset high scores for Simple Minesweeper, a game I downloaded from the Store, I needed to delete `settings.dat` and `settingsB.dat` from the `LocalState` folder. Depending on the game/app you're trying to reset, you may need to delete other files.